# Creating a Library with Local Module Dependency in Gradle MavenPublication

Tags: android, maven, gradle, maven-plugin

I'm trying to create a library module in Gradle that includes a local module as a dependency.No problem there until I publish the library using MavenPublication, the exported lib won't be able to access to local module. I'm looking for a clean solution to include the local module dependency in the published library's POM file without resorting to merging modules.

My lib gradle for my module i want to export :

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':apiClient')
}
```

I'm publishing the library using MavenPublication:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.x.lib'
            artifactId = 'my-lib'
            version = VERSION_NAME + "-release"
            
            dependencies {
                implementation project(path: ':apiClient')
            }

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.release
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'my-repo'
            url = "${project.buildDir}/maven-local-repo"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to properly include the apiClient dependency in the published POM file of my library so that client projects can use it without explicitly adding it to their dependencies?

The solutions that worked and i try to avoid in order to find a cleaner way :

- Include ApiClient as part (Copy the folders..) on the Lib i want to export
- Create ApiClient as a maven dependency. That will make the development and deploy procces ugly